# Вывод в Java. Не могу понять почему выводит именно так

Tags: java, arraylist

```
package test;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SomeClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        String b = null;
        String j = null;
        ArrayList<Animal> a = new ArrayList<Animal>();
        BufferedReader rs = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    while(true){
        b = rs.readLine();

        if (b.equals(""))
            break;
        j = rs.readLine();
        a.add(new Animal(b, j));
    }
    for (Animal item : a){
        item.printAll();
        System.out.println("=====================");
    }
}

static class Animal {
    static String color;
    static String name;
    public Animal(String a, String b){
        Animal.color = a;
        Animal.name = b;
    }
    public void printAll() {
        printColor();
        printName();
    }

    public void printColor() {
        System.out.println(color);
    }

    public void printName() {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

}

> //Прога должна записывать данные: цвет и имя. Но например пишу-
>
> СЕРЫЙ
>   Волк
>   Красная
>   Лиса
>
> А выводит:

Красная
Лиса
Красная
Лиса

Заранее спасибо

Comment: У вас статические поля для имени и цвета, это поля класса, они "общие" для всех экземпляров объекта, поэтому так.

Comment: Точно, спасибо огромнейшее

Answer (score 3):

Вы использовали статические переменные в объекте, в итоге это и привело к неправильному выводу информации, замените

```
static class Animal {
    static String color;
    static String name;
    public Animal(String a, String b){
        Animal.color = a;
        Animal.name = b;
    }
}
```

на

```
static class Animal {
    private String color;
    private String name;
    public Animal(String a, String b){
        this.color = a;
        this.name = b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте описания в чем ошибка у автора вопроса.